# Running Cypress through CircleCi

Tags: pipeline, cypress, circleci, end-to-end, xvfb

Cypress has been running great locally. When I try running it in the circle-ci pipeline then it has a number of issues. First, here is the relevant part of my workflow:

```
orbs:
  cypress: cypress-io/cypress@1.19.2
workflows:
  version: 2.1
  commit:
    jobs:
      - cypress/install:
          install-command: 'npm install --no-optional --unsafe-perm'

      - cypress/run:
          requires:
            - cypress/install
          start: 'lerna run start --parallel'
```

When I view the operations in circle-ci, it successfully compiled but immediately cancels

```
project/applicable-folder: ℹ ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.


Build was canceled
```

and in the build process I notice this line

`project/applicable-folder: Failed to load /root/project/.env.`

The .env is absolutely there.

`npx cypress run` does run after this but all of the tests fail since even the test for `cy.visit('/');` fails.

Why is the env file not successfully accessed? Am I missing a step that allows for this to run? Am I even supposed to allow it to run? I am uncertain about how to proceed.

I have also tried to use the build instead of start but this does not work any better.

I have also used a manual strategy:

test:e2e:
    docker:
      - image: docker-image
    steps:
      - checkout
      - restore_cache:
          keys:
            - v2-deps-{{ .Branch }}-{{ checksum "package-lock.json" }}
            - v2-deps-{{ .Branch }}-
            - v2-deps-
      - run: npm ci
      - save_cache:
          key: v2-deps-{{ .Branch }}-{{ checksum "package-lock.json" }}
          paths:
            - ~/.npm
            - ~/.cache
      - run:
          name: Run user acceptance tests
          command: npm run cy:run

This will result in a requirement for Xvfb to be installed.

Will this mean that it should work provided that that is installed? I would rather have the orb version work.

EDIT: I tried out the library `start-server-and-test`.

scripts are as follows

```
"cy:pipeline": "start-server-and-test up http-get://localhost:8080 cy:run"
"cy:run": "cypress run --headless --record"
"up": "lerna run start --parallel"
```

The new cypress/run

```
  - cypress/run:
      requires:
        - cypress/install
      record: true
      command: 'npm run cy:pipeline'
```

But I have been receiving the same errors,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was simple.

All I had to do was move the install-command from `cypress/install` to `cypress/run`.

```
  - cypress/install

  - cypress/run:
      requires:
        - cypress/install
      start: 'lerna run start --parallel'
      install-command: 'npm install --no-optional --unsafe-perm'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to watch [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J-xbNtKgXfY&list=WL&index=117&t=0s) great presentation from official circleci youtube channel on cypress integration, it should be helpful to resolve your question

Comment: I have watched that video and it is very informative. As far as I can tell, what I have setup should work.

Answer (score 0):

I think the webpack dev server is exiting immediately, is this `react-scripts` by any chance?

Comment: What is causing it to exit immediately? It is not using react-scripts.

Comment: I edited the question to include a `start-server-and-test` attempt. It tried to run the tests but failed to load `/` even though the plugin has an inherent wait built in. Which means that the plugin found  :8080 but cypress didn't?